# Differential equation: $y=2xy'+\frac{1}{(y')^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've encountered the following differential equation:

$y=2xy'+\frac{1}{(y')^2}$

I tried to differentiate in order to $x$ and then used $p=y'$. After some calculation, I arrived at the formula $ x = \frac{2}{p^3} + \frac{C_{1}}{p^2}$

Does anyone has any suggestion to solve the first equation?

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 2):

This is a [Lagrange Equation](https://www.math24.net/lagrange-clairaut-equations/) given as:  $~y=x\phi(p)+\psi(p).$ where $p=\frac{dy}{dx}$

Given equation can be written as

> $$y=2xp+1/p^2      ~~~~~~~~~~~.......(1)$$

On diff. wrt $x$,

$\Rightarrow dy=2xdp+2pdx-\frac{2}{p^3}dp$

$\Rightarrow -pdx=(2x-\frac{2}{p^3})dp~~~~~$  [I have used $dy=p dx$]

$\Rightarrow \frac{dx}{dp}+\frac{2x}{p}=\frac{2}{p^4};~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$   [Assuming $p \ne 0$]

Above Eq. is linear in $x$ and $p$ variable.

Hence its solution in parametric form is given as

> $$~x(p)= \frac{-2}{p^3}+\frac{C}{p^2}$$

From Eq(1),

> $$y(p)= \frac{-3}{p^2}+\frac{2C}{p}$$

**Singular Solution** SS is given by $p=0$, Putting this back into Eq.(1),
We get the SS as

> $$y(x)=0$$

Comment: 2 things : 1)It is meaningless to say "let us assume $dp \neq 0$". 2) It looks me strange that the singular solution depends on a parameter ($C$)...

Comment: @JeanMarie, Oops, Thanks for pointing it out, Edited.

Answer (score 0):

By eliminating parameter $p$, I find this (cartesian) equation for the singular solution:

> $$y=3x^{2/3}$$

Besides, let us look for a particular power solution of the differential equation :

$$y=ax^b$$

(which is a different issue). There exist exactly one such solution.

Indeed, we must have, for any $x \neq 0$ :

$$ax^b=2xabx^{b-1}+\dfrac{1}{(abx^{b-1})^2}\tag{1}$$

Multiplying LHS and RHS by $x^{-b}$, (1) is equivalent to :

$$a(1-2b)=\dfrac{1}{a^2b^2}x^{2-3b}\tag{2}$$

(2) cannot hold for any $x$ unless $2-3b=0$, and simultaneously $a^3b^2(1-2b)=1$.

This system of equations has a unique solution :

$$b=\dfrac23  \ \ \text{and} \ \ a=-\dfrac{3}{\sqrt[3]{4}}$$

Therefore, the differential equation has this power solution

> $$y=-\dfrac{3}{\sqrt[3]{4}}x^{2/3}\tag{3}$$

It corresponds to the case $C=0$ of the parametric equations given in the general solutions by @Axion004 and @math.